# how to read data from a table in database and insert into another database?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

i want to create a windows service for read data from one database and then insert data into an other database.  how can i do it ?

Can I read and copy my data with this stored procedure in sql without windows service or any other programs ?

My data changes every day and I need to update my database when data is changed can i run a stored procedure with a schedule?

If i can do it then my data is replace o duplicate ?

i want to save all my data and don't want to replace or duplicate it

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Are the DBs hosted on the same server ?

Comment: yes they are in the same server

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a Master-Slave Database Architecture.

This architecture will replicate the datas of one database to another.
Read in here for more info. All the CRUD operatiuons that you will be performing in Master DB will get replicated to Slave DB.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master/slave_(technology)

Comment: This is true. But I would like to add that you could also use SSIS to create a package do this, and schedule a package via SQL Server Agent to run.

Comment: Thanx for the valuable comment. Definitely SSIS is an another work around.

Answer (score 0):

There are different techniques to make such copying.
1. Database replication.
2. A trigger may copy specific changes to another database.

Comment: i don't want to read all of data in database
i just want to read one table in that database and copy its data into my database for use it

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you use sql server (you didn't write it, but it's natural for c# developers)

1. Yes, it is possible to create a windows service to synchronize 2 different databases.
   assuming you have the same table in both databases all you have to do is read the data from one database into a datatable, and send it to the other database (it's possible to send a datatable as a stored procedure parameter).

However, there might be better ways to handle this (such as replication).

1. yes, it is possible to create a scheduled job on sql server, that can run stored procedured.
2. it's up to you to decide if you want to duplicate the data or replace it. it depends on the  sql statement you will write.

Comment: please show me your suggestion
if it possible please write code for me
i'm a Beginner

Comment: i create the windows service but i have problem with it
first i read data from db1 and store it into a data set
its ok and don't have any problem
bet when i want to read data from dataset and insert into my db i face whit error !!!!

Comment: as others and I wrote, there are several ways to synchronize data between databases, and a windows service might not be the best solution for you.

If you have access from one database to another, then replication might be a better way for you to solve this problem, as it requires no code and can be configured directly on the database it self. If the 2 databases cannot access each other, then a window service may be a better solution.

Comment: let's Dissect my db and the other
my table has 5 field's id(int and incremental), hittype(int), timeofhit(time(7)), dateofhit(date), empno(int)
the other db has to many field's but i just want 4 of those field's to copy into my table
for this what should i do ?

Comment: if possible, I would go with the SSIS package method.

Comment: Why isn't it possible?

Comment: because servers are not same

Comment: You mean different versions?
anyway, if you want to use a window service you will have to do the following:
1. run a select statement on the source database every x time to find out if there are records to copy.
2. if there are records to copy, run a select statement on the source database to get them (the best way I can think of is to write a stored procedure that will return a result set only if records should be copied, then you can combine these steps.
3. run an update/insert statement on the target server with the data from the result set you got from step 2.

that's all there is to it.

Comment: is it possible for you to create a windows service code for me ?

Comment: No, not really.
I can help with specific questions, but I'm not in the habit of working for free.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using SSIS packages as well which is quite easy to use.
 
If you go with this option then you need to give source database and destination database conncetionstring. 
Also you need to have a clone table of the source table into the destination database. 
Then you need to create a sql job which will call SSIS package in first step and in second step you have to call created procedures which will get records from the clone table of the destination database after process is completed then truncate clone table. 
So that 
you have always new records to update existing records.

Let me know if you need more clarification how to setup job and SSIS package.

Also, you can use this option when database are located on different servers.

Regards,
Vishal Bagdai

Comment: please tel me more about this solution